# Salesforce security review - ID field fls create

Tags: security-review, checkmarx

In salesforce security review am getting a error **FLS create** which is for **ID** field. so when a FLS create error occurred, validated the isCreateable or isUpdatebale for update condtion.[image]

Here how to validate the error, When validated isCreatable for **ID** field error didn't occur ***but the record is not inserting***. (cant check isCreatable for ID field right?) How to manage both the FLS create issue and ID field issue.

And can please tell me should I validate both **isCreatable and isUpdateable for upsert** operation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Security Scanner tool is not as great when it comes to Apex.

1. I would ignore the reported error and implement the right way logically which is - Don't check Id isCreateable().
2. Yes, you should validate both isCreatable and isUpdateable for Upsert operation.

Comment: The Id field will always have `isUpdateable` as false.